# How to debug Vue.js e2e tests in WebStorm?

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I've been trying to add a '[Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)' for the e2e tests in my Vue.js app in WebStorm (or IntelliJ Ultimate).

This was easily done for the unit tests after following [their blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/how-to-debug-with-webstorm/) which addressed that.

However, I also want to use breakpoints when running the e2e tests. All of the articles and search results I've come across only mention unit tests in this context, but surely others are using their Jetbrains IDE to debug e2e tests in a Vue app?

How to configure my IDE's debug configuration so that I can hit breakpoints in the e2e tests of my Vue app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No special support for Nightwatch testing framework is currently provided; if you miss it, please vote for [WEB-16510](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16510) to increase its priority and be notified on any progress with it.

Nightwatch wiki provides step by step instructions to integrate it with Webstorm IDE - see https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Debugging-Nightwatch-tests-in-WebStorm.

But, as in Vue projects e2e tests are normally run with `vue-cli-service`, I'd suggest a different setup that works for me:

[image]

Comment: The setup in the GitHub link you've provided works perfectly for me!